# Understanding issues on git logs with multiple merges

Tags: git, merge

We have a workflow based on gitflow (with feature branches, release branches etc) and therefore a lot of merges.

We sometimes need to synchronize different deployments and our solution is to check the difference between the last "upstream" tag. (this synchronization is done through git-bundle and git-patch for security reasons). And I don't really understand what happens in the commit logs.

```bash
$ git log --topo-order --oneline
cb8daee (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'integ01'
307dc57 Merge branch 'feat02'
0b3e73b commit
bb31caf commit
bae2a31 Merge branch 'feat01'
8252585 commit
981887a Merge branch 'feat05'
7aa698a commit
5c6a89b commit
b47b19d (tag: v0.2) Merge branch 'integ01'
567aa0a commit
...
```

I would expect that

```bash
$ git log v0.2..HEAD
```

gives the same list of commits (until the 5c6a89b one) but I have a them plus a lot of other ones from previous merges.

If I do

```bash
$ git log --ancestry-path v0.2..HEAD
```

it looks closer to what I expect, but I miss some of the merged commits (I have all the merge commits though).

Why is that ?

I tried to reproduce the behavior on a simple example, without success, so maybe we do something wrong somewhere, but I cannot find where.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help with this if you would show the _graph_. Otherwise everything is flattened down with no topology.

Comment: one piece of advice : add `--graph` to have a clearer view of the history of your repo.

Comment: Add `--graph`, as @matt says.

Comment: "Snap" everybody. :)